# find in meteor server side, what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm doing this query on the server side, the collection has 1000 documents:

```
Data.find({}, {limit: 1}).count();
```

The result of this query is 1000

But if I make this query:

```
 Data.find({}, {limit: 1}).fetch().length
```

The result is 1

I imagine that is due to the fact that count() works over the entire collection, without taking in consideration the limit, is this assumption correct? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, limit only limits the amount of items in the cursor.

`Count()` counts all matches for your selector, so it's not influenced by a limit. [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#count)